# Merging two binary trees node sum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I was working on the problem of merging two binary trees node sum (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-binary-trees-node-sum/) and I was having trouble understanding some of the recursion. Why would you set the recursion statements to `t1.left` and `t1.right`? When you do this does `t1.left` equal two values?

I'm just not sure why we would set the recursion statements to t1.left`or`t1.right`

```
class newNode: 
def __init__(self, data): 
    self.data = data  
    self.left = self.right = None


def inorder(node): 
    if (not node): 
        return

inorder(node.left)  

print(node.data, end = " ")  

inorder(node.right) 


def MergeTrees(t1, t2): 
    if (not t1):  
        return t2  
    if (not t2): 
        return t1  
    t1.data += t2.data  
    t1.left = MergeTrees(t1.left, t2.left)  
    t1.right = MergeTrees(t1.right, t2.right)  
    return t1 

if __name__ == '__main__': 

# Let us construct the first Binary Tree  
#    1  
#    / \  
#    2   3  
# / \    \  
# 4 5    6  
root1 = newNode(1)  
root1.left = newNode(2)  
root1.right = newNode(3)  
root1.left.left = newNode(4)  
root1.left.right = newNode(5)  
root1.right.right = newNode(6)  

# Let us construct the second Binary Tree  
#    4  
#    / \  
# 1  7  
# /  / \  
# 3  2 6  
root2 = newNode(4)  
root2.left = newNode(1)  
root2.right = newNode(7)  
root2.left.left = newNode(3)  
root2.right.left = newNode(2)  
root2.right.right = newNode(6)  

root3 = MergeTrees(root1, root2)  
print("The Merged Binary Tree is:")  
inorder(root3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge the trees using recursion, you follow the typical formula:

1. Operate on the current node
2. Operate on one child
3. Operate on the other child

In this case, it's quite convenient the the merge can be done in-place for one of the trees.  You merge the current root node.  Then you recur on the left child, which merges `t2.left` into `t1.left`; you assign this to `t1.left` so that the merged left subtree cleanly replaces the original.  You do the same for the right subtree.

Is it clear yet?

Answer (score 1):

First make it possible to set the `left` and `right` branches when you are constructing a `Node` -

```py
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```

Now instead of mutating trees using `node.left = ...` and `node.right = ...`, we can construct them directly -

```py
# Let us construct the first Binary Tree  
#     1  
#    / \  
#   2   3  
#  / \   \  
# 4   5   6  

t1 = Node(1, Node(2, Node(4), Node(5)), Node(3, None, Node(6)))
```

Before we go on, let's implement `__str__` on `Node` so we can visualise the trees -

```py
class Node:
  def __init__(...):
    # ...

  def __str__(self, pre="", child=""):
    if self is None:
      return "()"
    else:
      return f"({self.data} {self.left} {self.right})"

print(t1)
# (1 (2 (4 None None) (5 None None)) (3 None (6 None None)))
```

Now let's implement `merge`. Having the ability to specify the `left` and `right` values in the `Node` constructor makes it easier to write this -

```py
def merge(t1, t2):
  if t1 is None and t2 is None:
    return None
  elif t1 is None:
    return t2
  elif t2 is None:
    return t1
  else:
    return Node(t1.data + t2.data, merge(t1.left, t2.left), merge(t1.right, t2.right)

print(merge(t1, t1))
# (2 (4 (8 None None) (10 None None)) (6 None (12 None None)))
```

Now we can see how `+` could easily some other operation. Adding another parameter to `merge` makes it possible to merge using any operation -

```py
def merge(f, t1, t2):
  if t1 is None and t2 is None:
    return None
  elif t1 is None:
    return t2
  elif t2 is None:
    return t1
  else:
    return Node(
      f(t1.data, t2.data),
      merge(f, t1.left, t2.left),
      merge(f, t1.right, t2.right)
    )

print(merge(lambda a, b: a + b, t1, t1))
# (2 (4 (8 None None) (10 None None)) (6 None (12 None None)))

print(merge(lambda a, b: a * b, t1, t1))
# (1 (4 (16 None None) (25 None None)) (9 None (36 None None)))
```

Or using `operator` module -

```py
from operator import add, mul

print(merge(add, t1, t1))
# (2 (4 (8 None None) (10 None None)) (6 None (12 None None)))

print(merge(mul, t1, t1))
# (1 (4 (16 None None) (25 None None)) (9 None (36 None None)))
```